# The local port 3000 is not available (CentOS ,browser-sync, VSCode Remote SSH)

Tags: centos, port, browser-sync, vscode-remote

I'm doing development with VSCode Remote SSH, where CentOS 7 is running.
I use BrowserSync to proxy remote URL, it was usually running on localhost:3000 and localhost:3001 (this is the default)
but some time ago after I played a little with VSCode extensions for this purpose I noticed, that VS Code Remote started to auto-forward ports 3000 and 3001 to some random ports like 581116 etc.
If I try to change 'Local address' on "ports" tab to 3000, I get error "the local port 3000 is not available'.
If I set up Browsersync to use ports 3002 and 3003 for example, VS Code forwards them as 3002 -> 3002, 3003 -> 3003, that is expected, but not with 3000 / 3001 anymore. I suspected that some unfinished process occupied this port, but I cannot detect any connected processes with `sudo lsof -i -P -n` and any other command I tried.
I tried also `npx kill-port 3000`, but this didn't help either.
What is happening and how can I claim my localhost:3000 back?